# finding strings between markers in objective-c

Tags: objective-c

I have one very long string.

In it are markers and between those markers are text.

example:

```
<body>blah blah blah</body><body>another string</body>
```

basically I want to iterate through the string and extract the text in between the markers. additionally I want to place each string of text into a separate string.

So essentially I'd end up with:

```
string1:blah blah blah
string2:another string
```

How would I do this?

Edit - I may not have been clear. the one string will have many many delimiters of the same type in. so the input string could literally be:

```
<body>blah blah blah</body><body>another string</body><body>blah blah blah</body><body>another string</body><body>blah blah blah</body><body>another string</body><body>blah blah blah</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If first delimiter appears in your text only once, you may use code:

```
NSArray *c1 = [text componentsSeparatedByString:@"<body>"];
if ([c1 count]<2) {
    // you don't have first delimiter
}
NSArray *c2 = [[c1 objectAtIndex:1] componentsSeparatedByString:@"</body>"];
if ([c2 count]<2) {
    // you don't have second delimiter
}
NSString *result = [c2 objectAtIndex:0];
```

You may use NSScanner as well:

```
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:text];
if (![scanner scanUpToString:@"<body>" intoString:nil]) {
    // there is no opening tag
}
NSString *result = nil;
if (![scanner scanUpToString:@"</body>" intoString:&result]) {
    // there is no closing tag
}
```

The second code snippet seems to be better.

If XML you try to parse gets more complicate it may turn to better to use NSXMLParser. But in such simple examples usage of NSXMLParser is too verbose.

Comment: very useful! although I'm not sure I fully understand this. How does the code grab what is in between the <body></body> tags? these tags can appear many times in one string.

Comment: in second snippet scanner will pass string until it encounter first delimiter. then scanner will eat and remember all characters from the string until second delimiter. first snippet does the same but it's behavior is more difficult to understand if there might be several opening and closing delimiters.

Comment: oh ok so in the second example the first delimiter is unnecessary.. right?

Comment: @SirYakalot, it depends on what you need. Giving code examples I replied your question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `componentsSeparatedByString` and `componentsJoinedByString`

```
NSString * dataString = [[NSString alloc] init];
dataString = [[dataString componentsSeparatedByString:@"<body>"] componentsJoinedByString:@","];
dataString = [[dataString componentsSeparatedByString:@"</body>"] componentsJoinedByString:@""];

NSArray *data = [dataString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

Then you would have an array of strings.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [NSRegularExpression](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to build a regular expression to find the text matches. It would be pretty simple if the delimiters are all the same. Find all the matches and build an array or new string with them:

```
NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"<body>(.*)</body>"
                                                                       options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                         error:&error];
```

Comment: Unfortunately, NSRegularExpression appeared in iOS only in 4.0. If you need to back support <4.0 you need to rely on something else.

Comment: Yes, but that was not a requirement of the question -- so the assumption is use of the latest sdk.  I think it's pretty rare for apps to target less than iOS 4 these days.

Comment: there are still about 5% of client base of my apps. I can agree with you it's already below threshold when it make sense not to support iOS below 4.